# Compile time tree structure

Tags: c#, tree, compile-time, class-hierarchy

I want to retrieve values from a tree stored in another system. For example:

```
GetValue("Vehicle.Car.Ford.Focus.Engine.Oil.Color")
```

To avoid typing errors and invalid keys, I want to check the name at compile time by creating an object or class with the tree structure in it:

```
GetValue(Vehicle.Car.Ford.Focus.Engine.Oil.Color)
```

Is there an easy way to do this in C# without creating classes for each tree node? Can I use anonymous classes or subclasses? Should I create the code automatically?

Comment: You could (should) create the code automatically

Comment: Do you mean that this is like a class hierarchy?

Comment: Yes, a class hierarchy. Oil.Color would probably be a string containing the key.

Comment: You could do this with a pile of properties and type casting, with a class tree or other similar methods, but it seems a bit of an odd thing to do -- if the structure you are using is hard-coded, then you only have one chance to mis-type. If it's not hard-coded, then you're going to run into problems trying to reproduce the tree structure twice -- much more chance of making mistakes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want compile-time checking, you need to define your structure using compile-time constructs in some way. You could use [T4 text template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) to automatically generate code from the tree structure.

Possible ways I can think of:

*Nested static classes*

```
public static class Vehicle
{
    public static class Car
    {
        public static class Ford
        {
            public static class Focus
            {
                public static class Engine
                {
                    public static class Oil
                    {
                        public static readonly string Color =
                            "Vehicle.Car.Ford.Focus.Engine.Oil.Color";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Namespaces and static classes*

```
namespace Vehicle.Car.Ford.Focus.Engine
{
    public static class Oil
    {
         public static readonly string Color =
             "Vehicle.Car.Ford.Focus.Engine.Oil.Color";
    }
}
```

(Note that you can't have both a class `Ford` in namespace `Vehicle.Car` and classes in a namespace `Vehicle.Car.Ford`.)

Answer (score 1):

- You can't do this without creating classes for each tree node
- Anonymous types and/or subclasses won't help here (at least I can't see how)
- You can generated the classes automatically, you will need to write a code generator for it, or use an existing one such as [t4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) or [CodeSmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/). You will still need to write some code even with an existing code generator to tell it how to generate your classes.

Answer (score 1):

Try some thing like this:

```
var Vehicle = new { Car = new { Ford = new { Focus = new { Engine = new { Oil = new {Color = "Red"}}}}}};
```

Now you can get each value with intellisence.

Although I prefer @dtb approach. Still I think my approach is quite light weight.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably find a way to do it with C# Extension methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

But there's probably no escape from some automatic code generation